# How can I get better at algorithmic thinking?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, contest-math

I have been practising for a an upcoming algorithmic thinking competition but have always found that when doing the past papers, I have never had enough time left to finish. I can do basically all of the questions but it just takes me a long time.

This competition doesn't test programming. Instead, it tests how you can create your own algorithms and think computationally to solve a problem.

Here are a couple of sample problems. 
[image]

[image]

[image: enter image description here[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oepNL.png)

So, do you have any tips that might help when doing these competitions or any advice that I could use while practising?

Thank you :)

Comment: "This competition doesn't test programming." it does : it tests if you understand recursivity, stacks, trees, and backtracking

Comment: Ok sorry. It doesn't require you to know any programming languages.

Comment: it does, you cannot solve an aribitrary large  backtracking problem (for example a sudoku) without writing the algorithm and running it (with its local variables, stack, etc.)

Comment: in the same way, if I ask you to compute $109809809389878927897 \times 30980980982$ on a paper, you'll have to understand the algorithm for integers multiplication, and run it, with its local variables, its loops, etc.

Comment: I have solved countless sudokus without writing any algorithm and running it. I guess you can solve it that way but all I am saying is that it is not completely necessary to know how to computer program first. You just need to know how to think logically. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I said to solve a "arbitrary large problem"; you'll need to write the algorithm and run it, rigorously, exactly as a computer would do when running a program. hence, you need to know how to write an algorithm (a program), and run it. this is exactly what means "knowing programming"

Comment: so the answer is : start by understand how to program, recursivity (linked lists), stacks and queues, trees, backtracking, graphs. and the most important :  understand how a computer does for running all these programs.

Answer (score 1):

*user1952009* is correct that to get better at doing such questions you ultimately need to understand how to **construct** algorithms and **prove** them correct and **implement** them (whether on paper or in a program). However, since no one has answered this question, I'll give some answers. Note that my answers are a mix of both standard algorithms and mathematical tricks, which is not at all surprising. Developing **efficient** algorithms always involve mathematics.

**Grid question**

Look for patterns. The initial grid has at most two '1's in every row and column, but has a row with only one '1' and a column with only one '1'. That eliminates all possible answers except one. Done!

**Game question**

This requires a proper grasp of quantifiers. A position is losing if every move leads to a winning position for the opponent, and is winning if some move leads to a losing position for the opponent. Since the game is player-symmetric, we can discard the turn information and just look at the number of counters left of each colour. The optimal strategy is simply to choose a move to a winning position if possible. Notice that the rules enable you to make the number of white counters the same modulo $4$ as after your previous turn, and similarly for the number of black counters modulo $3$. Unravelling two moves ahead shows that you can ensure both. Since the final winning position is $(0,0)$, you can win if you can get there modulo $(4,3)$ on the very first move. If you cannot, the analysis is slightly more tricky but not hard to figure out if you think about it (simply build the game tree bottom-up from $(0,0)$; if you don't know what bottom-up is, read up on dynamic programming).

**Maze question**

This is a standard single-source shortest path problem, which is additionally trivial to implement on paper!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I couldn't grasp @user21820 explanation of Grid question because I'm not smart enough, not because it is not exhaustive enough. No sarcasm... Maybe he found things that I will say below too trivial/obvious to state them though.

I would try though to provide my own explanation, how do I see it. It took me some time, but I can't say how much, because I though on it intermittently. I wonder how much time consumption for each puzzle is acceptable for this particular challenge. Don't think it was more than 30-60 minutes total. I have zero skill in solving such problems. Or almost zero. But I want to learn it, about to register at Codeforces.

My understanding is this: let's consider each rows and columns as sets of numeric elements. We have 8 sets with elements defined. Whether we swap rows or columns, we still get these 8 sets. The order of elements changes in some of them, but no matter how many swaps we do, we still need to have 8 sets with initial elements for each grid in a process, including final.

From given answers, only answer D's 8 sets match 8 sets of initial grid. So, the answer is D.